# Filter (or 'cut') out column that begins with 'OS=abc'

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, cut

My .fasta file consists of this repeating pattern.

```
>sp|P20855|HBB_CTEGU Hemoglobin subunit beta OS=Ctenodactylus gundi OX=10166 GN=HBB PE=1 SV=1
asdfaasdfaasdfasdfa
>sp|Q00812|TRHBN_NOSCO Group 1 truncated hemoglobin GlbN OS=Nostoc commune OX=1178 GN=glbN PE=3 SV=1
asdfadfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasd
>sp|P02197|MYG_CHICK Myoglobin OS=Gallus gallus OX=9031 GN=MB PE=1 SV=4
aafdsdfasdfasdfa
```

I want to filter out only the lines that contain '>' THEN filter out the string after 'OS=' and before 'OX=', (example line1=Ctenodactylus gundi)

The first part('>') is easy enough:

```
grep '>' my.fasta | cut -d " " -f 3 >> species.txt
```

The problem is that the number of fields is not constant BEFORE 'OS='.

But the number of column/fields between 'OS=' and 'OX=' is 2.

Comment: The term `filter out` is very ambiguous - it could mean `output only this` or `output everything except this`.

Comment: @ed-morton Good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-P` option to enable PCRE-based regex matching, and use lookaround patterns to ensure that the match is enclosed between `OS=` and `OX=`:

```
grep '>' my.fasta | grep -oP '(?<=OS=).*(?=OX=)'
```

Note that the `-P` option is available only to the GNU's version of `grep`, which may not be available by default in some environments.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this statement.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO `awk` will be more feasible here(since it could take care of regex and printing with condition part all together), could you please try following.

```
awk '/^>/ && match($0,/OS=.*OX=/){print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-6)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Ctenodactylus gundi
Nostoc commune
Gallus gallus
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                    ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>/ && match($0,/OS=.*OX=/){            ##Checking condition if line starts from > AND matches regex OS=,*OX= means match from OS= till OX= in each line, if both conditions are TRUE.
  print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-6)    ##Then print sub string of current line, whose starting point is RSTART+3 to till RLENGTH-6 of current line.
}
' Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F' O[SX]=' '/^>/{print $2}' file
Ctenodactylus gundi
Nostoc commune
Gallus gallus
```

Comment: Works great, I like the simplicity of this one also. Thanks for teaching me this.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution:

```
$ sed -nE '/>/ s/^.*OS=(.*) OX=.*$/\1/p' .fasta
Ctenodactylus gundi
Nostoc commune
Gallus gallus
```

`-n` so that the pattern space is not printed unless requested; `-E` (extended regular expressions) so that we can use subexpressions and backreferences. The `p` flag to the `s` command means "print the pattern space".

The regular expression is supposed to match the entire line, singling out in a subexpression the fragment we must extract. I assumed OX is preceded by exactly one space, which must not appear in the output; that can be adjusted if/as needed.

This assumes that all lines that begin with `>` will have an `OS= ...` fragment **immediately** followed by an `OX= ...` fragment; if not, that can be added to the `/>/` filter before the `s` command. (By the way - can there be some `OT= ...` fragment **between** `OS=...` and `OX= ...`?)

Question though - wouldn't you rather include some identifier (perhaps part of the "label" at the beginning of each line) for each line of output? You have the fragments you requested - but do you know where each one of them comes?

Comment: good question, but at this time, I am interested to know the species origin it comes from.